# How to check for collisions between all the instances of my class in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently trying to print on the screen when a collision occurs but don't know how to do it for only 1 class. I know how to make 2 objects collide from different classes but I don't know how to do it for one classes with 1000 different objects

I tried using some in game pygame functions like pygame.rect.contain but i had no idea where to go from there.
Thanks for helping me guys.

The code is listed below :

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
import time

Height = 800
Width = 800
Steps = 0
running = True

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((Height, Width))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")


class Ball(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, delta_x, delta_y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.delta_x = delta_x
        self.delta_y = delta_y

    def draw(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(display, WHITE, (self.x, self.y, 1, 1))

    def update(self):
        self.x += self.delta_x
        self.y += self.delta_y

        if self.x < 0:
            self.delta_x = self.delta_x * -1
        if self.x > Width - 5:
            self.delta_x = self.delta_x * -1

        if self.y < 0:
            self.delta_y = self.delta_y * -1
        if self.y > Height - 5:
            self.delta_y = self.delta_y * -1


list = []
for i in range(1000):
    ball = Ball(random.randrange(0, Width - 5), random.randrange(0, Height - 5),
                random.randint(-10, 10), random.randint(-10, 10))

    list.append(ball)

while running:
    display.fill(BLACK)
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    # Update

    # Draw
    for ball in list:

        ball.draw()
        ball.update()

    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.display.update()
    print(clock.tick(60))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the equal points, the you've to compare the x and y coordinates of the points.

e.g.

```py
for i in range(len(list)):
    eq_list = [j for j in range(len(list)) if i != j and list[i].x == list[j].x and list[i].y == list[j].y]
```

For example you can paint the colliding points in read for this approach:

```py
class Ball(object):

    # [...]

    def draw(self, color):
        pygame.draw.rect(display, color, (self.x, self.y, 1, 1))
```

```py
for i in range(len(list)):
    ball = list[i]

    collide = any([j for j in range(len(list)) if i != j and list[i].x == list[j].x and list[i].y == list[j].y])
    ball.draw(RED if collide else WHITE)

    ball.update()
```

Note, this approach will be slow for 1000 points and thus 1000*1000 collision tests.

A much better solution would be to use a 1000x1000 field and set a state in the field, if an object is on it. This would reduce the collision test to some test if the state in the filed is set or not.

Create a field with boolean states:

```py
obj_grid = [[False for i in range(Height)] for j in range(Width)]
```

Get a list of the positions of the objects and set the corresponding states in the field. Pass the field to the `Ball.update` method. After updating and drawing the the filed has to be cleared, because the positions have changed. Use the list of positions for this, because this is much faster than "clearing" the entire field. I added som bound checks, because some of your objects seems to be out of bounds (probably this bug has to be fixed, too).

```py
# collect the postions of the items
poslist = [(ball.x, ball.y) for ball in list]

# set the positions in the field
for pos in poslist:
    if pos[0] < Width and pos[1] < Height:
        obj_grid[pos[0]][pos[1]] = True

# update and draw
for ball in list:
    ball.update(obj_grid)
    ball.draw()

# set the positions in the field
for pos in poslist:
    if pos[0] < Width and  pos[1] < Height:
        obj_grid[pos[0]][pos[1]] = False
```

In the `Ball.update` method the positions on the pending way of the path have to be tested. If any filed is stated, then the objects collide. I stored the state in an attribute `self.collide`. If the state is set, the object is enlarged and painted in red, to visualize the collisions. Of course you can do something else like changing the direction, too:

```py
class Ball(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, delta_x, delta_y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.delta_x = delta_x
        self.delta_y = delta_y
        self.collide = False

    def draw(self):
        color, size = (RED, 5) if self.collide else (WHITE, 1)
        pygame.draw.rect(display, color, (self.x, self.y, size, size))

    def update(self, obj_grid):

        # check if the object is colliding on his way
        pos = [self.x, self.y] 
        new_pos = [self.x + self.delta_x, self.y + self.delta_y]
        self.collide = False
        while not self.collide and pos != new_pos:
            if abs(pos[0]-new_pos[0]) > abs(pos[1]-new_pos[1]):
                pos[0] += 1 if self.delta_x > 0 else -1
            else:
                pos[1] += 1 if self.delta_y > 0 else -1
            self.collide = pos[0] < Width and pos[1] < Height and obj_grid[pos[0]][pos[1]]

        self.x += self.delta_x
        self.y += self.delta_y
        if self.x < 0:
            self.delta_x = self.delta_x * -1
        if self.x > Width - 5:
            self.delta_x = self.delta_x * -1
        if self.y < 0:
            self.delta_y = self.delta_y * -1
        if self.y > Height - 5:
            self.delta_y = self.delta_y * -1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**: *After fixing a bug in earlier version that slowed it down a great deal, I've gone further and implemented a number other improvements / optimizations since this seems like a very viable technique.*

Here's a runnable implementation of one approach that seems to work very well. To to avoid comparing the position of every pair of balls every iteration — nearly 1,000,000 comparisons for 1,000 balls — it uses a strategy of subdividing the screen into M x N divisions or "bins" and "classify"ing each of the balls into of them based on its current position on the screen. Effectively sorting them in a very inexpensive way since only some relatively simple calculations are involved.

Once that is done, only the pairs of balls within each bin need to be compared to one another, which is faster because each bin will hold only a subset of all of them. There's a trade-off in doing this because, although the more bins you create — so there's a smaller number of balls there are in each one — it also increases the number of bins that need to be processed.

The colors colliding balls are first changed to specified color to mark them for deletion in a follow-on step — the color isn't actually used to draw anything — only as a simple way of marking them. I did this to avoid printing when collisions are detect to which would have slowed things down too much.

In the sample code below there are 8 x 8 = 64 bins, which will initially each contain an average of only 1000 / 64 (15.625) balls, assuming a random distribution.

The result seems to run very fast.

```
from itertools import combinations
from copy import deepcopy
from math import sqrt
import pygame
from random import randint

BLACK = 0, 0, 0
WHITE = 255, 255, 255
RED = 255, 0, 0
GREEN = 0, 255, 0
BLUE = 0, 0, 255

NUM_BALLS = 1000
MARKED = RED  # Color used to indicte ball collided.
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 800
M, N = 8, 8  # Number of screen sub-divisions in each dimension.

MARGIN = 5  # Size of space around edges.
MAX_SPEED = 10
MAX_DELTA = round(sqrt(2 * MAX_SPEED**2))
MAX_DELTAX_X, MAX_DELTAX_Y = MAX_DELTA, MAX_DELTA
MAX_X, MAX_Y = WIDTH-MARGIN, HEIGHT-MARGIN
EMPTY_BINS = [[[] for i in range(M)] for j in range(N)]
WM, WN = WIDTH // M, HEIGHT // N  # Dimensions of each sub-division.


class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, delta_x, delta_y, color=WHITE):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.delta_x, self.delta_y = delta_x, delta_y
        self.color = color

    def draw(self, display):
        # Using Surface.fill() can be faster than pygame.draw.rect().
        display.fill(self.color, (self.x, self.y, 1, 1))

    def update(self):
        self.x += self.delta_x
        self.y += self.delta_y

        if self.x < 0:
            self.x = 0
            self.delta_x = -self.delta_x
        elif self.x > MAX_X:
            self.x = MAX_X
            self.delta_x = -self.delta_x

        if self.y < 0:
            self.y = 0
            self.delta_y = -self.delta_y
        elif self.y > MAX_Y:
            self.y = MAX_Y
            self.delta_y = -self.delta_y


def classify(balls):
    """ Sort balls in bins. """
    bins = deepcopy(EMPTY_BINS)
    for ball in balls:
        m, n = ball.x // WM, ball.y // WN
        try:
            bins[m][n].append(ball)
        except IndexError:
            raise IndexError(f'bins[{m}][{n}] -> {ball.x}, {ball.y}')
    return bins

def detect_collisions(balls):
    """ Find all colliding balls and return whether any were found.
    """
    bins = classify(balls)  # Separate balls into bins.
    collisions = False
    for m in range(M):
        for n in range(N):
            if bins[m][n]:  # Non-empty?
                for a, b in (pair for pair in combinations(bins[m][n], 2)):
                    if(a.x == b.x and a.y == b.y and (a.color != MARKED or
                                                      b.color != MARKED)):
                        a.color = b.color = MARKED
                        collisions = True
    return collisions

def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = pygame.display.set_mode((HEIGHT, WIDTH))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

    balls = [
        Ball(randint(MARGIN, MAX_X), randint(MARGIN, MAX_Y),
             randint(-MAX_DELTAX_X, MAX_DELTAX_X), randint(-MAX_DELTAX_Y, MAX_DELTAX_Y))
           for _ in range(NUM_BALLS)
    ]

    # Main loop.
    remove_collisions = False  # No collisions first iteration.
    while len(balls):
        display.fill(BLACK)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    return

        # Remove any collisions found.
        if remove_collisions:
            balls[:] = [ball for ball in balls if ball.color != MARKED]

        # Update display.
        for ball in balls:
            ball.draw(display)
            ball.update()

        # Check after ball updates.
        remove_collisions = detect_collisions(balls)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

main()
```